# What is the purpose of name mangling?

Tags: python

While doing Python koans I came accross name mangling. The koan explained that name mangling exists to avoid name clash issues when subclassing. The koans is below:

```
class Dog(object):
    def name(self):
        return "Fido"

    def __password(self):
        return 'password'

def test_double_underscore_attribute_prefixes_cause_name_mangling(self):
    """Attributes names that start with a double underscore get
    mangled when an instance is created."""
    rover = self.Dog()
    try:
        #This may not be possible...
        password = rover.__password()
    except Exception as ex:
        self.assertEqual('AttributeError', ex.__class__.__name__)

    # But this still is!
    self.assertEqual('password', rover._Dog__password())
```

I don't understand why rover.__password() isn't possible. I am assuming it's because there is a name clash. But where is the clash? I only see one `__password()` for `rover`. Can anyone give a more clear example of when name mangling is needed?

Comment: Raymond Hettinger provides a very good example for the use of name mangling in his talk [Python's Class Development Toolkit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HTLu2DFOdTg&feature=youtu.be&t=34m) around 34m into the video.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Fair enough

Comment: @LukasGraf that video was a little over my head but I think I understand now. What I got out of it was that __foobar basically renames to _Class__foobar.